# FBSDKSharingDelegate callback not working, even when post works fine

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, facebook-sdk-4.0

**FBSDKSharingDelegate callback is not working.**  I can post to facebook fine with the ios SDK, but I'd like to detect if the post was successful and take additional action to notify the user.  However, the callback is not working for me.  The delegate methods are not being called and I don't know why.

Using ios8, Parse as my backend.  In Parse, the user is linked to FB.  I'm using the IOS simulator.

What I've tried:
I've ensured that publish permissions are granted, saved, and linked to the Parse user.  I've run a check and "publish_actions" are detected OK.  The posting works fine as I can see the post on the facebook account.  It's just the callback that is not working.  I've checked my fb setup and it looks fine.  For good measure at the very bottom I've included that relevant code from my app delegate.  I've blocked out confidential keys with XXXX.

**Code:**

1st: See if user is logged in to Parse, if not, send to sign in and link to facebook account.  Once that is done, I request "publish" permissions and link that additional permission to the Parse user.  I know this works b/c when I recompile, it remembers the "publish" permissions and goes right to into the post.

```
@interface FacebookAPIPost () <FBSDKSharingDelegate>
@end

@implementation FacebookAPIPost
-(void)shareSegmentFacebookAPI {    //if statement below

    //1) logged in?, if not send to sign up screen
    //2) else if logged in, link account to facebook account, then send post
    //3) else send to post b/c signed up and linked already.
    PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
    if(!currentUser) {
        [self pushToSignIn];
    } else if(![PFFacebookUtils isLinkedWithUser:currentUser]){
        [self linkUserToFacebook:currentUser];
        NSLog(@"user account not linked to facebook");
    } else {
        [self shareSegmentWithFacebookComposer];
    }
}


-(void)linkUserToFacebook:currentUser{

    [PFFacebookUtils linkUserInBackground:currentUser withPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"] block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if(error){
            NSLog(@"There was an issue linking your facebook account. Please try again.");
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"facebook account is linked");
            //Send the facebook status update
            [self shareSegmentWithFacebookComposer];
        }
    }];
}


-(void)shareSegmentWithFacebookComposer{
if ([[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] hasGranted:@"publish_actions"]) {
    [self publishFBPost]; //publish
} else {
    NSLog(@"no publish permissions"); // no publish permissions so get them, then post


    [PFFacebookUtils linkUserInBackground:[PFUser currentUser]
                   withPublishPermissions:@[ @"publish_actions"]
                                    block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                                        if (succeeded) {
                                            NSLog(@"User now has read and publish permissions!");
                                            [self publishFBPost];
                                        }
    }];
```

**Here is where the post gets made:**

```
-(void) publishFBPost{
        FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [FBSDKShareLinkContent new];
        content.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[self.selectedSegment valueForKey:@"linkToContent"]];
        content.contentTitle = [self.selectedProgram valueForKey:@"programTitle"];
        content.contentDescription = [self.selectedSegment valueForKey:@"purposeSummary"];

    PFFile *theImage = [self.selectedSegment valueForKey:@"segmentImage"];
    NSString *urlString = theImage.url;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    content.imageURL = url;

    FBSDKShareDialog *shareDialog = [FBSDKShareDialog new];

    [shareDialog setMode:FBSDKShareDialogModeAutomatic];
//    [FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self.messageTableViewController withContent:content delegate:self];
    [shareDialog setShareContent:content];
    [shareDialog setDelegate:self];
    [shareDialog setFromViewController:self.messageTableViewController];
    [shareDialog show];
}
```

Delegate methods below are not working.  Meaning after the post is complete, I can see it on the FB account, but none of these delegate methods execute.

```
#pragma mark - delegate methods

- (void)sharer:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer didCompleteWithResults:(NSDictionary *)results {
//    if ([sharer isEqual:self.shareDialog]) {
        NSLog(@"I'm going to go crazy if this doesn't work.%@",results);

        // Your delegate code
//    }
}

    - (void)sharer:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
    {
        NSLog(@"sharing error:%@", error);
        NSString *message = error.userInfo[FBSDKErrorLocalizedDescriptionKey] ?:
        @"There was a problem sharing, please try again later.";
        NSString *title = error.userInfo[FBSDKErrorLocalizedTitleKey] ?: @"Oops!";

        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
    }

    - (void)sharerDidCancel:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer
    {
        NSLog(@"share cancelled");
    }
```

**Console output:**
The only message I get back after posting is after a few seconds this message appears:

```
plugin com.apple.share.Facebook.post invalidated
```

Please help!

**Footnote: appDelegate**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    // Initialize Parse.
    [Parse enableLocalDatastore];
    [Parse setApplicationId:@"XXXX"
                  clientKey:@"XXX"];
    [PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions:launchOptions];


    //Initialize Facebook
    [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
    return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}


//Method added for facebook integration
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                          openURL:url
                                                sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                       annotation:annotation];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I am too late answering this question but someone else could trap into this as well, that's why sharing my knowledge.

[As per Facebook API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/protocol/FBSDKSharingDelegate/)

```
sharer:didCompleteWithResults: Sent to the delegate when the share completes without error or cancellation.
The results from the sharer. This may be nil or empty.
```

its probably because this delegate method is only get called when the post is successfully shared. In case of failure the other delegate method `sharer:didFailWithError:`get called. I think Facebook API should not need to add the *result* parameter is that case.

So in my experience if `sharer:didCompleteWithResults` whenever this is called that would mean success.

Comment: I've tested many cases and `sharer:didCompleteWithResults` is called wouldn't mean the post has been posted successfully. You can open the sharing dialog and press on "Done" button or "Close" button to cancel posting, and still see `sharer:didCompleteWithResults` method has been called.